# How to add link in the Ajax/JSON live search using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am using this search method that I've seen in a certain post here, and  it works fine, it shows just like this:

[image: when link is not added]

but after adding code that would display a link for that live search it shows:

[image: when link code is added]

what i want is to display a link that looks like the first picture.
here is my ajax code:

```
  <script>
    var base_url = "<?=base_url()?>";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").keyup(function(){
            if($("#search").val().length>1){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url :  base_url + "Isidran/searchFirm",
                    cache: false,
                    data:'search='+$("#search").val(),
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#finalResult').html("");
                        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        if(obj.length>0){
                            try{
                                var items=[];
                                $.each(obj, function(i,val){
                                    var href = '<?php echo site_url('Profile/view'); ?>'+ "/" + val.userID + "/" + val.username;
                                    items.push($("<a href='"+href+"'>").text(val.firstName + " " + val.lastName + " (" + val.username + ")"));
                                });
                                $('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
                            }catch(e) {
                                alert('error on request..');
                            }
                        }else{
                            $('#finalResult').html($('<p>').text("No Data Found"));
                        }

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Error while request..');
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

my controller:

```
public function searchFirm(){

        $search =  $this->input->post('search');
        $query = $this->Blog_model->getFirm($search);
        echo json_encode ($query);
    }
```

My model:

```
//sorry for this query, but it works fine any suggestion to make this better 
//will be very helpful
public function getFirm($search){

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `blog`.`tbl_users`, `blog`.`tbl_userinfo`, `blog`.`tbl_uploads` 
WHERE (`tbl_users`.`userID`=`tbl_userinfo`.`user_ID` AND `tbl_users`.`userID`=`tbl_uploads`.`user_ID`  AND `tbl_users`.`username` like '%$search%')
OR (`tbl_users`.`userID`=`tbl_userinfo`.`user_ID` AND `tbl_users`.`userID`=`tbl_uploads`.`user_ID` AND `tbl_userinfo`.`firstName` like '%$search%') 
OR (`tbl_users`.`userID`=`tbl_userinfo`.`user_ID` AND `tbl_users`.`userID`=`tbl_uploads`.`user_ID`  AND `tbl_userinfo`.`lastName` like '%$search%')");

return $query->result();

}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, i know the basic of css. and a bit of tricks of it

Comment: do you know what display:block and clear does?

Comment: yep, do i need to set the #finalResult into display:block and clear: both?